# My app doesn't show Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android application using Google maps, I have edited the code to get current user location but when I run the code , the maps don't appear. I am not getting any error or warning . All I can see on my emulator is grey screen with a marker on it.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
package com.example.shubham.mapsandgeolcationservices;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static android.location.LocationManager.*;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }

        }





@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng ShanivarWada= new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ShanivarWada).title("Shaniwar Wada"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ShanivarWada,18));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<23){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
        }
        else {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }else{
               locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                LatLng ShanivarWada= new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ShanivarWada).title("Shaniwar Wada"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ShanivarWada,18));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which emulator are you using?

Comment: have you added sha-1 of your system in google console ?

Comment: have you given permissions of location in manifest.

Comment: @ Avinash Yes , i have given the permission in manifest.

Comment: @when the morning comes nexus 6 API 23

Comment: @sanketkachhela i did not get your question

Comment: in src package , there are 3 folder - release, main and debug. add your maps api key in all the folders.

Comment: @Ace, hi, please use google apis image for the emulator.